# Javascript Regex inside matched string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string like this

```
<html>
    [[Wayfinder? &amp;startId=`0` &amp;outerClass=`art-hmenu` ]] &amp;
    &amp; 
</html>
```

I want to change all `&amp;` that inside of `[[` and `]]` will be replaced by `&`

How to do that with javascript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
str.replace(/\[\[(.*)?]]/, function(match) {
    return match.replace(/&amp;/g, '&');
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Jtv5a/

Comment: Better: Change `/\[\[(.*)?\]\]/` to `/\[\[(.{4})?\]\]/`

Comment: @qwertymk - I don't really see how that's any better. All it'll do is prevent the second regex from running if the text inside is less than 4 characters long. Not really that much of a benefit.